# Emigrating from Ireland to Australia. What should I know?

Tags: visa, working-visas, australia, ireland

Like the title says, I'm planning on emigrating from Ireland to Australia next year and I'm wondering is there a comprehensive list of things I should know before I go.

I have a degree in Computer Science and just under 2 years professional experience. Is there a specific type of working visa I should apply for?

Answer (score 4):

Important piece of advice — save some money. Australia is an expensive place. It can be quite daunting at first. You can’t help but notice the cost of groceries and rent relative to Irish prices. Ensure you have sufficient cash for a bond (deposit) on an apartment and to allow for a few weeks of not having any earnings.

Contract work is the way of life in Australia. Have your CV prepared and send it to recruitment agencies a few days before you arrive in your chosen city. You can search for the agencies online that are most appropriate to your industry. Don’t forget your cover letter, which should detail when you are available for interviews. Note that you must be interviewed by recruiters before they take you on their books. If you are anxious to start working as soon as possible, this will save you waiting for an email/phone call when you get there.

Consider a temporary position. This allows you to familiarize yourself with the market and earn Australian dollars in the meantime. Be prepared to start from the bottom. If you work hard, it will be recognized.

Relocating your life is not easy. Do everything possible to get as organised as possible before you leave. Be excited. Australia is a wonderful country to live in. The people, the lifestyle, the food, the weather, and the natural beauty of the land are things that are hard to give up

Good-luck :) !

Comment: I don't know about Australia but Ireland actually felt quite expensive to me (before the crisis, admittedly). Groceries were certainly more expensive than in most places in Europe, except Scandinavia, and rents weren't particularly cheap either.

Comment: Well it differs :) according to Indices Differences:                                 Consumer Prices in Australia are 8.94% higher than in Ireland
Consumer Prices Including Rent in Australia are 18.76% higher than in Ireland
Rent Prices in Australia are 45.71% higher than in Ireland
Restaurant Prices in Australia are 1.78% lower than in Ireland
Groceries Prices in Australia are 11.79% higher than in Ireland
Local Purchasing Power in Australia is 14.52% higher than in Ireland

Comment: It's entirely possible that Australia is even more expensive, like I said I have no idea. I was just mildly surprised because you made it sound as if Ireland was somehow cheap. These data would in any case be valuable additions to your answer, ideally with some details on the source/methodology.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you finish 2 years of professional work experience and apply for any of the two PR visas (189 or 190).

Once you have 2 years of work experience under your belt, apply for skills assessment from ACS. You need to show them your ICT graduation and evidence of work experience in your occupation. Sit the IELTS (or PTE-Academic or any other recognized English language tests) and score the best you can. With this, if you can score 60 or more points (55 for the 190 visa, but needs state sponsorship), you would be eligible for the PR visas.